# Get all object from Django ForeignKey Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models, an Event and a suggestedName. suggestedName has a ForeignKey relationship with Event as well as a IntegerField called 'votes'. I want to get the top 5 suggestedNames associated with an Event.

My models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank = 'TRUE', primary_key='TRUE')
    version = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable = False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField()
    trained = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(default = 0)


class suggestedName(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

What I have in my view is this:

```
e = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)

suggestedN = e.suggestedName_set.order_by('votes')[:5].reverse()
```

But I'm not getting any results.

Comment: Why are you setting `primary_key` field nullable?

Comment: Oops. Yeah, I'll take that out, but I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
e.suggestedname_set.order_by('-votes')[:5]
```

Or specify a related name

```
class suggestedName(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True, null = True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='suggestions')
```

and then,

```
e.suggestions.order_by('-votes')[:5]
```

Comment: Still nothing. Won't even work if I have it be e.suggestedName_set.all(). Also I just realized I forgot to add a possibly relevant line up in my question. One sec

Comment: Then very clearly you dont have data associated with the event. Go to the django admin console and try adding some data

Comment: I do. There are currently 2 suggestedNames in there right now and both are associated with the event in question.

Comment: Sorry i missed that - `suggestedname_set` should be all lower case . Also, if you have set a `related_name`, use that instead of `suggestedname_set`

Comment: Looks like my answer should work. Please verify that it is the same `event` object.

Comment: I know it all looks just fine which is why I'm so damn confused. I'm passing it down as a context and then looping through it on my webpage. I know the HTML is correct because I used to have this as a ManyToMany and it showed up just fine